# disabling javascript plugin based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding a website essentially for three different breakpoints (desktop, tablet, mobile). I have a javascript plugin running an automatic image change for my full width background.  As I resize my window to the tablet and mobile breakpoints, can I disable the javascript plug in and make it stop running when the window is smaller than ***px?

Comment: No, but you could add a check to the Javascript `if screen.width < xxx....`

Comment: Yes you can "disable" that javascript plugin. But the question is *how*. And that depends on what the plugin is, how it is coded, etc.

Comment: Depends entirely on the plugin, if/how it supports being disabled, if it supports automatically disabling itself under certain resolutions, etc... There is no way of answering this in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var minWidth = 800 // minimum width of screen
if ($(window).width() <= minSize) {
     // do nothing
}
else {
     // continue script
}
```

If you wanted it to be width as well as height:

```
if ($(window).width() <= minWidth && $(window).height() <= minHeight) {
```

Or something similar.